# I changed mysql root password and I cant access It. password contained some chars

Tags: mysql, password

using this command I changed root password

```
mysqladmin -u root password fg$pkh@567fghu
```

And now I cant access mysql. Is this because mysql parse the chars other than what I expect?

Also I completely removed and installed mysql and Problem is extant.
How do I remove mysql so that I get rid of password?

Comment: More than likely bash is interpreting from the command line. Try using `mysql -u root -p` then type your password at the prompt.

Comment: I already tried that, It's not working

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get from mysql - is there anything in your logs related to this ?

Comment: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Well, you could try and set it (again) in an init script as described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Tried it like OP, and like @NickW suggested. Some chars sometimes cause Problems. In the end, I was using a much longer Password, with only [A-Za-z0-9].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you need to reset your password you can try this it should work

```
service mysqld stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql --user=root mysql
update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

Now stop mysql

```
pkill mysql
```

and restart the service

```
service mysql start
```

You should be able log on with your new password.

Comment: awesome, It worked. You described Thing way better than mysql documentation.