# Catch 22 on moving from old-style passwords and mysql_upgrade

Tags: mysql

I have an ancient MySQL database that I've kept running for a very long time, probably about 14 years.
Apparently, I'd missed to run mysql_upgrade on it *long* ago, perhaps during the upgrade from 4.x to 5.x (and ever since).
Now, after upgrading to 5.6.22 (from 5.5.x) yesterday, I can no longer log in, and I also can't seem to solve the issue.
Apparently, old-style password hashes have been deprecated for over 10 years, but I have never seen any warnings saying so, until it stopped working just now.

The first symptom something was wrong was this:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2049: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled) when trying to connect
```

I get the same error using `mysql -u root -p`.
I got past that by using the `--skip-secure-auth` option to the mysql command. After that, [the documentation says you should update your password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-upgrades.html):

```
SET old_passwords = 0;
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password',
Password = PASSWORD('DBA-chosen-password')
WHERE (User, Host) = ('user1', 'localhost');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This fails:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'plugin' in 'field list'
```

The solution to **that** error appears to be to run `mysql_upgrade`, which updates the mysql.user table to add the plugin column. However, **that also fails**, with this wonderful error:

```
# mysql_upgrade -u root -p
Enter password: 
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

My guess is that this is because there is no `--skip-secure-auth` option to `mysql_upgrade`, so it can't log in.
I tried to disable secure-auth for the server, but if I did it correctly, it didn't help. (Possibly because mysql_upgrade that ships with 5.6.x uses it by default and doesn't allow you to disable it?)

Does anyone have a solution to this? I'm not above things like temporarily disabling passwords etc. while solving it; the server is only accessible from localhost, and I'm the only local user.

Comment: This might help you http://serverfault.com/questions/606072/i-changed-mysql-root-password-and-i-cant-access-it-password-contained-some-char/606085#606085

Comment: @Iain thank you, it did! I must admit I doubted that it would, since setting the password when logged in didn't help (when "plugin" is missing, it uses the old password style, so it just re-wrote an old-style hash when you log in using --skip-secure-auth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread Iain linked to in the comments solved the issue.

After following those instructions, I restarted the server and tried to log in as usual (with no `--skip-secure-auth`), which worked.
I then ran `mysql_upgrade -u root -p`, which also worked. After that and a mysqld restart, everything seems to work as it should, and my root user has a "new" password (41-char long hash, rather than 16).

With the root user fixed, you should be able to migrate other users as described in [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-upgrades.html), which lays out the steps both to identify which passwords you need to update, and how to do just that.