# reset mysql password without knowing current password

Tags: mysql

I am unable to remember the password for mysql database.

Using the `ALTER USER` statement does not work to update the password.

does anyone know how to do this?

I am entering:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordhere';
```

the error I am receiving is

```
"You must reset your password using the ALTER USER 
statement before executing this statement."
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset or recover admin account password for MySQL?](http://serverfault.com/questions/4309/how-to-reset-or-recover-admin-account-password-for-mysql)

Comment: Hey Karen, can you please let us know some other details, OS, MySQL version, commands you have tried and the errors you are getting.

Comment: I am currently going through the working solution in that post now Slipeer but I'm having problems with that too

@AnthonyFornito I am entering ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordhere' ... the error I am receiving is "You must reset your password using the ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

Comment: @Karen can you edit you question to include details in the question, it hard to tell what is a comment and what is a command in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I changed mysql root password and I cant access It. password contained some chars](http://serverfault.com/questions/606072/i-changed-mysql-root-password-and-i-cant-access-it-password-contained-some-char)

Answer (score 0):

As described in mysql [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html), the syntax for password change is:

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Also - similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac

Comment: This still throws up the same error... i'm trying the post that slipeer posted but i'm having trouble with that too